# Why is the collator node producing and finalizing blocks at such a fast rate?

Tags: cumulus, sync

I am reading the Cumulus docs on running a node:

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus#build--launch-a-node

Why is it that when I run:

```sh
./target/release/polkadot-collator --tmp --chain westmint
```

blocks seem to get produced and finalized at a very fast rate:

```sh
2022-04-19 10:56:55 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 2 at #1800    
2022-04-19 10:56:56 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 3 at #3600    
2022-04-19 10:56:57 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 4 at #5400    
2022-04-19 10:56:57 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing, target=#10482356 (16 peers), best: #7481 (0xb64f…40c4), finalized #7168 (0xa1a9…fb0d), ⬇ 526.5kiB/s ⬆ 13.6kiB/s    
2022-04-19 10:56:57 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing, target=#1987773 (5 peers), best: #5628 (0x2de9…a6b7), finalized #0 (0x67f9…98c9), ⬇ 3.0MiB/s ⬆ 32.3kiB/s    
2022-04-19 10:56:58 Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:51659.    
2022-04-19 10:56:59 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 5 at #7200    
2022-04-19 10:57:00 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 6 at #9000    
2022-04-19 10:57:02 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 7 at #10800    
2022-04-19 10:57:02 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing 1240.7 bps, target=#1987773 (5 peers), best: #11839 (0x31c1…256f), finalized #0 (0x67f9…98c9), ⬇ 2.2MiB/s ⬆ 18.5kiB/s    
2022-04-19 10:57:02 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 1326.2 bps, target=#10482357 (23 peers), best: #14123 (0x6ff5…9915), finalized #13824 (0xc608…ba94), ⬇ 385.9kiB/s ⬆ 8.5kiB/s
```

Comment: When you just want to do testing, you can use `--chain westmint-dev` instead. This provides an ephemeral and deterministic development chain.

Comment: That is good to know. TY Oliver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are syncing. That means you are just importing the old blocks and that can happen much faster than what the actual block time is. When you have reached the tip of the chain, you will import blocks as they are being produced. So, much slower, under perfect conditions currently around 1 block every 12 seconds.